# CellForRowAt: Returns nil even if cell is visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project I have a `tableView` with an `ImageView` where the Images are downloaded from the internet.

Since the download can take a while, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I check that the cell is still visible before displaying it, this is to make sure that the image isn't displayed in the wrong cell.

However, since I made a change in the code, which in my opinion shouldn't change anything, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function returns `nil` even if the cell is visible.

Here is my working code:

```
ExcursionImageDownloader.shared.getImage(from: url, completion: {(image) in
                if let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExcursionTableCell {
                    updateCell.thumbnailImage.image = image
                    print("Image View size is: \(updateCell.thumbnailImage.frame.size)")
                }
            })
```

The getImage calls the completion whenever the image finished downloading. In the second line where I declare the updateCell I make sure that the cell is still visible and it works perfectly.

Now I changed the code to the following:

```
ExcursionImageDownloader.shared.thumbnailImage(from: currentExcursion, url: url, completion: { image in
                print(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)
                print(indexPath)
                if let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExcursionTableCell {
                    print("Displaying image")
                    updateCell.thumbnailImage.image = image
                }
            })
```

Again the completion handler gets called without problems, however, the updateCell now always is nil and thus the thumbnailImage never gets assigned. To make sure that the cell is visible I added the 2 print statements and this was the output:

```
Optional([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]])
[0, 0]
Optional([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]])
[1, 0]
Optional([[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]])
[2, 0]
```

As you can see the cell is clearly visible and I have absolutely no Idea why the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil`. In my opinion this could be a bug, however, i'm not sure.

So is there a mistake in my code or is this effectively a bug?

**Update**

Here is the complete cellForRowAt function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Safely downcast cell, if it's not existing due to any reason it will create and return an empty cell
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExcursionCell", for: indexPath) as? ExcursionTableCell else {return UITableViewCell()}

        //Since we are working with sections that have different amount of cells, we will get the correct excursion for this cell from the excursions array that is nested inside the excursionsSections array.
        let currentExcursion = self.excursionsSections[ indexPath.section].excursions[indexPath.item]


        cell.title.text = currentExcursion.title
        cell.descriptionText.text = currentExcursion.thumbnailDescription
        cell.thumbnailImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceHolder").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        //Customize the cell
        cell.descriptionText.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.thumbnailImage.tintColor = UIColor.primary

        //Download image 

        if currentExcursion.imageURLs.count > 0 {
            let url = createURL(withImage: currentExcursion.imageURLs[0], width: thumbnailSize().width, height: thumbnailSize().height)

            ExcursionImageDownloader.shared.thumbnailImage(from: currentExcursion, url: url, completion: { image in
                print(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)
                print(indexPath)
                if let updateCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExcursionTableCell {
                    updateCell.thumbnailImage.image = image
                }
            })

        setColor(selected: false, cell: cell)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I normally put the load of the image logic inside the cell implementation and call a callback in cellForRowAt method

Comment: The logic isn't just downloading the image since I use core data, therefore I preferred to have it seperate.

Comment: Where are you executing this code? can you post to see the bigger picture?

Comment: I've added the code, however, as i stated in update i do not think this is relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry I think the relevant part is the cellForRowAt method

Comment: A sorry, my mistake :]

Comment: I ussually put an assert condition instead of return UITableView() you can check that the class of cell returned by  `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`is ExcursionTableCell ? use         `let className : String = String(describing: type(of: updateCell))
        debugPrint(className)` and remove the conditional cast to ExcursionTableCell let me know

Comment: I did as you said, however, the 'cellForRowAt:' still returns nil even without the downcast

Comment: I think you don't need call cellForRowAt at all you are in the cellForRowAt method, my bad for not see it before, you need just `cell. thumbnailImage.image = image` in the closure, test and let me know

Comment: It is necessary because I download the image an since this is an async process it can take a while, so if the user scrolls through the table and the original cell is not visible anymore after the download finished, the requested image will be displayed in a different cell. I have already tested this and can confirm this behaviour

Comment: I use this approach in several projects but using SDWebImage to load the images, and works without problems, also using alamofire you never need to call cellForRowAt method

Comment: I think if you put the logic of image retrieval inside the cell implementation must work without problems only in prepareForReuse you need set the imageView.image = nil

Comment: I will try this however, i do not know why my approach wouldn't work, especially if the first method worked which was almost identical